# Is it possible for Wordpress MutliSites to use the Main Blog Posts table?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Prefer not to use a plugin, if its simple.

So I have my main Blog (id: 1) This is where I post.  For each post I have a Meta Field `multi check-boxes` (4 choices: Site 1, Site 2, Site 3, Site 4)   I would like my `subsites` to use the posts from the Main Blog if their checkbox is selected for the post.

I thought maybe I can use `pre_get_posts()` and tried this, but it's not giving ideal results.

```
    function gnl_site_query( $query ) {

    $current_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

    if ($current_blog_id !== 1) :

        if ($query->is_main_query() || $query->is_admin()) :

            $meta_query = array();

            $type = $query->get('post_type');

            if ($type == 'post'):

              switch_to_blog(1);

              $meta_query[] = $query->get('meta_query');
              $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'gnl_post_attributes_sites',
                'value' => $current_blog_id,
                'compare' => '=',
              );
              $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

              restore_current_blog();

            endif;

          //print_r($query);

        endif;

    endif;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'gnl_site_query' );
```

Comment: seems like you want the result on frontend but your code runs for backend `|| $query->is_admin()`, when , where and what you want to achieve, please clear your question first.

Comment: i want it to run on the front end of the sub sites and backend of the subsites... really i have no use for the dashboards of the sub sites.. users will only have access to the main blog site.. post articles and select which site/domain the article will belong to (1 or many) ... but if i an super admin went to the backend of the sub site, they can see which articles are posted for testing... does that make sense?